# High level bluetooth / UART structure in Android app

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently modifying a working application that makes use of the micro USB port on an Android device to transmit and receive serial commands. I am attempting to get this application to work over bluetooth (low energy) in a similar manner. I managed to emulate a serial port by making TX and RX characteristics with GATT and communication works perfectly in testing.

My question is mainly about how I should go about passing an instance of this bluetooth service to the main (parent) activity.

```
    Main Activity
    | Bluetooth Activity
    | | Bluetooth UART Service
```

Based on the crude structure above, what is the best way to go about passing the service reference instantiated in the Bluetooth Activity to the Main Activity? I have considered making the Bluetooth Activity the launcher, then passing the reference via parcelable but I would like to maintain the UART over USB option.

Answer (score 1):

No, Activity is just UI class in Android. You should use Service for long running operations because it does not depend on device screen opientation and can still be running even if app gets closed. Create some 'BluetoothManager', put it into Service. In Application start that service. Your BluetoothActivity will bind to that service to do pairing. When it completes, Activity will unbind from Service and terminate, but Service will be still alive (BIND AND START SERVICE). You MainActivity will bind to it, get 'BluetoothManager' instance and use it for transferring data.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading up on binding services now. I am having a difficult time understanding how to implement this alongside the USB uart classes though. There are 4 classes involved: UARTActivity, UART, Bluetooth Service, and UARTApplication. I believe the Bluetooth Service simply needs to replace the UART class, but implementing it is a little vague to me